# Can a detail have two masters?

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access

I'm struggling with how I would set up a database for a situation where you have people (non anonymously) filling out questionnaires. The relationship between people and questionnaires is many-to-many--a person completes multiple questionnaires, and a questionnaire is completed by multiple people. So, I have a PERSON table, a QUESTIONNAIRE table, and a join table (PERSON-QUESTIONNAIRE).

But where do I put the info appearing in the questionnaires themselves? Questionnaire items have two parts (two fields), one with a question or statement people will respond to (ITEM) and one with space for the response (RESPONSE). Assuming all this goes in a separate table, what does this table join with? (The QUESTIONNAIRE table ... a QUESTIONNAIRE can have multiple QUESTIONNAIRE-ITEMS?)

And, if I'm correct about that last point, I can't for the life of me figure out how to set up a DB grid (in Delphi) that would display the ITEM and RESPONSE fields for a selected questionnaire and selected person. (I know how to code master/detail relationships with db-aware components, but this is like a detail with two masters.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have a table QUESTIONNAIRE-ITEMS (the questions) and a separate table QUESTIONNAIRE-RESPONSES (the answers), because there will be multiple answers for a single question, those from multiple persons. The former gets a foreign key to QUESTIONNAIRE, while the latter gets foreign keys to both QUESTIONNAIRE-ITEMS and PERSON.

In fact, the PERSON-QUESTIONNAIRE table could be omitted, since that information could be queried from the other tables. So for the design I suggest:

- Surveys: ID (PK), Description, etc...
- Users: ID (PK), Name, etc...
- Questions: ID (PK), SurveyID (FK), Question, etc...
- Answers: ID (PK), QuestionID (FK), UserID (FK), Answer, etc...

The view for the DBGrid will be based on a query like:

```
SELECT 
  Question, 
  Answer,
  ...
FROM 
  Questions INNER JOIN Answers ON Questions.ID = Answers.QuestionID
WHERE
  Questions.SurveyID = :SurveyID AND Answers.UserID = :UserID
```

In another part of you GUI, you select the `SurveyID` and `UserID` parameters.

And as a bonus: the query to acquire surveys and users, as an alternative to your separate join table, will look like :

```
SELECT
  Surveys.ID,
  Users.ID
FROM
  Users INNER JOIN (
    Answers INNER JOIN (
      Questions INNER JOIN (
        Surveys
      ) ON Questions.SurveyID = Surveys.ID
    ) ON Answers.QuestionID = Questions.ID
  ) ON Users.ID = Answers.UserID
GROUP BY
  Surveys.ID,
  Users.ID
```

Comment: Would QUESTIONNAIRE-RESPONSES be linked to PERSON, or PERSON-QUESTIONNAIRE (as Alanyst suggested)?

Comment: Like I say: RESPONSES will be linked to ITEMS and to PERSON.  (Answers is linked to both Questions and Users, sorry for the renaming).

Comment: Note that this design works so long as a user will only respond to the same questionnaire once.  If they need to be able to re-take the questionnaire, then the PERSON-QUESTIONNAIRE table will be needed and responses (answers) will need to reference that instead of PERSON directly.

Answer (score 3):

ITEM and RESPONSE should be different tables; there is a one-to-many relationship between them.  (An item belongs to a questionnaire, but many people can provide responses to that item, so each item will have many responses.)

I recommend a setup like this:

```
PERSON  <---- PERSON_QUESTIONNAIRE ----> QUESTIONNAIRE
                        ^                       ^
                        |                       |
                        |                       |
                     RESPONSE      ----->     ITEM
```

I don't have any suggestions about how to set up the DB grid (not a Delphi guru) but sometimes getting the design kinks worked out will help the technical solution become clearer.

Comment: Nicely outlined, but this setup doesn't really let you know which response was made by which person.

Comment: It does: `RESPONSE --> PERSON_QUESTIONNAIRE --> PERSON`

Comment: You are right, it does, I was probably thinking about something else. But there's another thing about this setup that I'm not sure is taken care about (at least you are not explicit about whether it is). It's that a response can possibly reference an item and a person/questionnaire pair that do not really reference the same questionnaire (that is, there's no mentioning about a constraint that would make sure the two things are related to the same questionnaire).

Comment: @AndriyM: That's true, there is nothing to constrain that the questionnaire record is the same.  That can't easily be captured as a schema constraint without really complicating the model, and in practice it tends not to be a huge risk.  If one is paranoid, one can write app logic to double-check the relations at appropriate times, like when the response record is created.